# How to use 2 different ngModel in the parent component for one child component elements?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-module

I have a child component with 2 input text-fields at once. I need to pass **`ngModel`** for each of them in/to the parent component (of course in one directive), and both of them they are required and must be checked by **`!form.valid`** How can I achieve this? Is there a way how to sue a kind of object for **`[ngModel]="name"`**

For more details regarding `*.ts` files etc., here is [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbwsqn?ctl=1&embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

**child**:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="password" 
           name="{{inputNamePass}}" 
           [(ngModel)]="modelPass" 
           (ngModelChange)="modelChange.next($event)" 
           required pattern=".....">
</mat-form-field>
<br><br>
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="password" 
              name="{{inputNamePassConfirm}}" 
              [(ngModel)]="modelPassConfirm" 
              (ngModelChange)="modelChange.next($event)" 
              required>
</mat-form-field>
```

**parent**:

```
<form #f="ngForm">
    <app-input [name]="'name for password'" 
               [name]="'name for password confirm'"
               [ngModel]="name"
               ngDefaultControl>
     </app-input>
</form>
```

Comment: Why cannot you change the aliases in your input property?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: You have same alias as 'name'  in both inputs. @Input('name') Change other alias to some other string like --> @Input('nameConfirm') and use this to pass the string in <app-input [name]="'Name'" [nameConfirm]="'nameOtherConfirm'".....>

Comment: @Avij: and what about `[ngModel]="name"` in `<app-input ...`. You can just pass one `[ngModel]="xxxx"`in the parent directive.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use @Output() and EventEmitter to emit the outputs whenever you need to the parent component?

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: It's there. Please check the posted [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbwsqn?embed=1&file=src/app/input.component.html)